# Java apache FTPServer and common.net FTPClient

Tags: java, jboss, ftp, apache-commons

I am trying to upload file on a java FTPServer.

The file transfert is OK, but all uploaded file have an extra 6ko data.

I use the embedded method to launch the FTPServer in an EJB service bean needed for an application

Here is the code i use:

```
package com.cs3Drender.ftpservice;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Local;

import org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServer;
import org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.Authority;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpException;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager;
import org.apache.ftpserver.listener.ListenerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.PropertiesUserManagerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.SaltedPasswordEncryptor;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.BaseUser;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.WritePermission;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Service;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class FtpServerServiceLocal
 */
@Service
@Local(FtpServerServiceLocal.class)
public class FtpServerService implements FtpServerServiceLocal 
{   
private FtpServer server = null;

@Override
public void create() throws Exception 
{
    FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();        
    ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();

    // set the port of the listener
    factory.setPort(2221);


    // replace the default listener
    serverFactory.addListener("default", factory.createListener());

    // create new user
    serverFactory.setUserManager(addUser("jboss", "azerty", "c:/tools"));

    // start the server
    server = serverFactory.createServer();
}

@Override
public void start() throws Exception 
{
    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (FtpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void restart() throws Exception
{
    try {
        server.stop();
        server.start();
    } catch (FtpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void stop() 
{
    try {
        server.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    stop();
    server = null;      
}

public UserManager addUser(final String username, final String password, final String ftproot)
{
    PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
    userManagerFactory.setFile(new File("c:/jbossusers.properties"));
    userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new SaltedPasswordEncryptor());
    UserManager um = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();

    BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
    user.setName(username);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.setHomeDirectory(ftproot);

    List<Authority> authorities = new ArrayList<Authority>();
        authorities.add(new WritePermission());        
    user.setAuthorities(authorities);

    try {
        um.save(user);
    } catch (FtpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return um;
}
}
```

And a simple client:

```
package client;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

import com.cs3Drender.session.RenderSessionRemote;

public class Client 
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* get a initial context. By default the settings in the file
     * jndi.properties are used.
     * You can explicitly set up properties instead of using the file.
     */
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
    properties.put("java.naming.provider.url","localhost");

    try
    {
        InitialContext context= new InitialContext(properties);
        RenderSessionRemote beanRemote=(RenderSessionRemote)context.lookup("RenderSession/remote");
        //System.out.println(beanRemote.render("test"));
        try {
            FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
            ftp.connect("localhost", 2221);
            ftp.login("jboss", "azerty");
            //ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            //ftp.enterRemotePassiveMode();
            ftp.setAutodetectUTF8(true);
            String filename = "bug sheep 2.png";
            ftp.storeFile(filename, new FileInputStream("c:/"+filename));


            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }catch(NamingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I don't realy understand why transfert data size is wrong.

Also the trace log of the server contains no error.

11:52:28,548 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] CREATED
11:52:28,549 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] OPENED
11:52:28,550 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] SENT: 220 Service ready for new user.

11:52:28,552 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] RECEIVED: USER jboss
11:52:28,553 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] SENT: 331 User name okay, need password for jboss.

11:52:28,553 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] RECEIVED: PASS *****
11:52:28,561 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.command.impl.PASS] Login success - jboss
11:52:28,561 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] SENT: 230 User logged in, proceed.

11:52:28,562 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] RECEIVED: PORT 127,0,0,1,12,190
11:52:28,563 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] SENT: 200 Command PORT okay.

11:52:28,563 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] RECEIVED: STOR bug sheep 2.png
11:52:28,705 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.command.impl.STOR] File uploaded /bug sheep 2.png
11:52:28,706 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] SENT: 150 File status okay; about to open data connection.

11:52:28,706 INFO  [org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter] SENT: 226 Transfer complete.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I have to set the transfer type manually to Binary mode.

```
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```